# NSPredicate returns duplicate values

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm having a problem when I filter my data. I have two tables, `patient` and `consultation`, that have a one to many relationship such that `consultation` contains the patient id. When I store the data in Core Data, I get the patient list in the `UITableView`, but when I filter each patient consultation by id using `NSPredicate` in the second `UITableView` I'm geting duplicate values.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getAllConsultations
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Consultation" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    NSString *Id = idPatientConsultation;
    int idPatient = [Id intValue];
    NSLog(@" id Patient Consultation : %@",Id);


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_patient == %i",idPatient];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *arrayConsultations = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Nombre de Consultations : %d",arrayConsultations.count);
    NSMutableArray *mutConsultationsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayConsultations];

    return mutConsultationsList;

}
```

array consultation log :

```
"<Consultation: 0x8d91680> (entity: Consultation; id: 0x8d7a840 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p117> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-03-25 13:28:11 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 24;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = aaaaaaaa;\n    observation = rien;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = \"55 kg\";\n    pouls = 60;\n    taille = \"1,80 m\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12,52\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0x8d5d840> (entity: Consultation; id: 0x8d88350 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p118> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-02-27 11:09:03 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 21;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = \"tout va bien\";\n    observation = sava;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = 60;\n    pouls = 80;\n    taille = \"1.65\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12.42\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0x8d5fa50> (entity: Consultation; id: 0x8d7de80 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p121> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-03-25 13:28:11 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 24;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = aaaaaaaa;\n    observation = rien;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = \"55 kg\";\n    pouls = 60;\n    taille = \"1,80 m\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12,52\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0x8d5fab0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0x8d80030 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p124> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-02-27 11:09:03 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 21;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = \"tout va bien\";\n    observation = sava;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = 60;\n    pouls = 80;\n    taille = \"1.65\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12.42\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0x8d647e0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0x8d7baa0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p127> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-02-27 11:09:03 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 21;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = \"tout va bien\";\n    observation = sava;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = 60;\n    pouls = 80;\n    taille = \"1.65\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12.42\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0x8d655a0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0x8d70300 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p129> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-03-25 13:28:11 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 24;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = aaaaaaaa;\n    observation = rien;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = \"55 kg\";\n    pouls = 60;\n    taille = \"1,80 m\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12,52\";\n})"
```

) 
2014-04-02 10:15:58.555 doctorApplication[2983:a0b]  Nombre des consultations : 6

here is the code that store data in the data base

```
-(void)listeDesConsultations{

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://127.0.0.1:8888/services/consultation.php" parameters:nil

     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {

     NSLog(@"JSON out : %@",responseObject);

     ConsultationsTab = (NSArray *) [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"items"];

     NSLog(@"nombre des elements : %d", ConsultationsTab.count );

     for (Consultation *consultation in consultationsList) {
         [consultation.managedObjectContext deleteObject:consultation];
     }

     [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];



     for (int i=0; i<ConsultationsTab.count; i++) {


Consultation *consultation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Consultation"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


         NSDictionary *consultationDic = [ConsultationsTab objectAtIndex:i];

        // NSLog(@"your name is : %@ %@", [consultationDic objectForKey:@"id_consultation"], [consultationDic objectForKey:@"id_patient"]);

         //id consultation//
         NSString *idConsultation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[consultationDic objectForKey:@"id_consultation"]];
         int idValue = [idConsultation intValue];
         NSNumber *idNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idValue];

         consultation.id_consultation = idNumber;

         NSString *idPatient = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[consultationDic objectForKey:@"id_patient"]];
         int idVal = [idPatient intValue];
         NSNumber *idNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:idVal];

         consultation.id_patient = idNum;

         NSString* strDate = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"date_consultation"];
         NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
         [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

         NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
        // NSLog(@"Date de consultation : %@",date);

         consultation.date_consultation = date;




         consultation.taille = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"taille"];
         consultation.poids = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"poids"];
         consultation.pouls = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"pouls"];
         consultation.motif = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"motif_consultation"];

         consultation.observation = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"observation"];
         consultation.temperature = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"temperature"];
         consultation.tension_arterielle = [consultationDic objectForKey:@"tension_arterielle"];



     }



     NSError *error;
     if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
     {
         NSLog(@"Problème d'enregistrement : %@",[error localizedDescription ] );
     }

     consultationsList = [self getAllConsultations];
     [self.tableConsultation reloadData];
     NSLog(@"hello");



 }

     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {

     NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",error]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];
 }];

 }
```

before delete :

```
Consultation list (
"<Consultation: 0xa1456e0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa137b80 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p197> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-03-25 13:28:11 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 24;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = aaaaaaaa;\n    observation = rien;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = \"55 kg\";\n    pouls = 60;\n    taille = \"1,80 m\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12,52\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0xa1459a0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa13d5d0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p198> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-02-27 11:09:03 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 21;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = \"tout va bien\";\n    observation = sava;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = 60;\n    pouls = 80;\n    taille = \"1.65\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12.42\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0xa145a70> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa138eb0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p202> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-02-27 11:09:03 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 21;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = \"tout va bien\";\n    observation = sava;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = 60;\n    pouls = 80;\n    taille = \"1.65\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12.42\";\n})",

"<Consultation: 0xa145b40> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa127be0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p203> ; data: {\n    \"date_consultation\" = \"2014-03-25 13:28:11 +0000\";\n    \"id_consultation\" = 24;\n    \"id_patient\" = 2;\n    motif = aaaaaaaa;\n    observation = rien;\n    patient = nil;\n    poids = \"55 kg\";\n    pouls = 60;\n    taille = \"1,80 m\";\n    temperature = \"37\\U00b0C\";\n    \"tension_arterielle\" = \"12,52\";\n})"
```

)

after delete :

```
 2014-04-02 11:55:24.406 doctorApplication[6760:a0b] Consultation list (
 "<Consultation: 0xa1456e0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa137b80 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p197> ; data: <fault>)",

 "<Consultation: 0xa1459a0> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa13d5d0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p198> ; data: <fault>)",

 "<Consultation: 0xa145a70> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa138eb0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p202> ; data: <fault>)",

 "<Consultation: 0xa145b40> (entity: Consultation; id: 0xa127be0 <x-coredata://AF78BE86-9E6A-487C-9E49-F720ACF831E4/Consultation/p203> ; data: <fault>)"
```

)

Comment: Show the log for `arrayConsultations`.

Comment: there are only 2 consultation for this patient and it show me 6

Comment: If you look at the ids they are different, it would appear you are inserting them more than once in the first place

Comment: check your coredata db (open using a tool like Liya . https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/liya/id455484422?mt=12 ) and verify you have not included duplicated data into this

Answer (score 1):

However you created the data and added it to the data store was wrong - you do actually have duplicate data in the data store.

You can see in your log that you have a set of items with the requested `id_patient`, and in that set each is a different object, some with duplicate `id_consultation`.

Probably you did not check for existing items with the specified `id_consultation` / `id_patient` when you import your data. You should check and update existing instances instead of just creating new instances.

Comment: how can i do that sorry but im new in ios develpement
the thing is that i parse them from a web service i delete the old data and add it to the base when i do such thing its ok but when i comment the parsing function and read only from the databese in offline mode it duplicate each time i pass from a patient to another

Comment: Log the consultations you delete. I suspect sometimes you aren't actually deleting any (because `consultationsList` is empty) but it's hard to know...

Comment: is there anyone ti help me pls :)

Comment: And you log directly the server response data and `consultationsList` after processing (is duplication on server or in processing logic)?

Comment: the insertion is ok but the duplication coma after :/